# How to concatenate var names in javascript?

Tags: javascript

How can i concatenate var names to declare new vars in javascript?:

```
var foo = 'var';
var bar = 'Name';
```

How can i declare variable varName?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why would you need to do that? Chances are, you're doing something wrong.

Comment: It make Javascript harder to read because you can't search where declare variable by using simple search like this("var [variable name]").

Comment: I have pre-declared var names that the user might be invoke based on user text input.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try something like:

```
window[foo + bar] = "whatever"; 
alert(varName);
```

do not use the eval function unless you are absolutely certain about what's going in. window[] is much safer if all you're doing is variable access

Comment: An additional reason to not use eval is that strict mode ECMAScript 5 does not allow eval to inject new variables

Answer (score 1):

WARNING: VaporCode! Off the top of my head...

```
window[foo + bar] = "contents of variable varName";
```

Does that work?

Comment: how can i go about the problem?

Answer (score 1):

To dynamically declare a *local* variable (i.e. `var fooName`), I guess you could use `eval`:

```
eval('var ' + foo + bar);
```

Best to avoid `eval` though, if you can avoid it (see [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/86513/why-is-using-javascript-eval-function-a-bad-idea)).

A better way is to set an object property. Defining a global variable is equivalent to setting a property on the global object `window`:

```
window[foo+bar] = 'someVal';
```

You can substitute `window` for another object if appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

Locally:

```
this[foo+bar] = true;
```

Globally:

```
window[foo+bar] = true;
```

Answer (score -3):

there may be a better way but eval should do it

```
eval('var ' + foo + bar);
```

Comment: @Babiker: Eval really is a bad practice, and dangerous, especially considering your comment about using user input to define what variable you'll be using. Not that anything a user can do in JS can be dangerous if your server is secure anyway, but still...
using window[foo+bar] is definitely safer.