# JS: how do I concatenate a variable into a API call with the dot syntax?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am trying to pass a parameter in a function, which I will use in a Highcharts file.

```
function getID (ID) {
    chart+ID+.series[0].update({
        ....do something
    )};
}
```

When I try to concatenate the ID that I get from the function, to the update call; I get an error saying

unexpected token "."

How do I use the ID in the update function? I thought that the + sign would concatenate strings, so

```
chart+ID+.series[0]
```

is the same as, with ID='1', to

```
chart1.series[0]
```

Comment: it does that is not a string though, is chart part of an object or array, such as someObj.chart

Comment: so how do you actually include a parameter, in a case like this?

Comment: you can do someObj['chart'+ID]

Comment: To answer the question, you'll have to show what "chart" is. It's probably not possible to do without some seriously undesirable hackery, so if you add more context to your question a better solution can be suggested.

Comment: Not that much of an expert; do I use the Obj keyword and close the whole API call in square brackets?

Comment: @newbiez no, that suggestion would require a different setup (and possibly the proper approach).

Comment: Pointy: "chart" is the name of the Highcharts chart that I have created; I have multiple charts on the same html file, so I need to update these charts and instead than write 10 times the same code, which is the same except the name of the chart, I am passing a parameter with a number used as ID.

Comment: try this window['chart'+ID].series[0], possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/918995/how-to-concatenate-var-names-in-javascript

Comment: ArtisticPhoenix: Sadly it won't work; I get an error (it consider the content of the square bracket as undefined). EDIT: to make it work I need to put only 'chart' in quotes; probably you made a typo with the quote on ID

Comment: ^yea there was a typo for about 30 seconds, you must have tried it then

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `chart1` is a global variable, you can do:

```
window['chart'+ID].series[0].update(...);
```

because global variables are automatically turned into properties of the `window` object.

If it's not a global variable, you can't do this. It would be best to make `chart` an array, rather than having `chart1`, `chart2`, etc. Then you could do:

```
chart[ID].series[0].update(...);
```

Comment: Bingo....I have it declared as global variable and now it works fine! So what is the "window" at the beginning doing?

Comment: I explained that. All global variables are implicitly properties of the `window` object, which represents the context of a web page in Javascript.

Comment: But you really should change to using an array, even if it is a global variable. Accessing variables this way is poor coding style.

Comment: Sorry, I was not aware of what this window object is; I went to read about it (I am new to JS). Indeed it makes sense to use an array; I need to access in various places to this variable and parameter, so it makes more sense to use an array. Thanks!